# Telling RestSharp *not* to add a specific HTTP header

Tags: c#, json, http-headers, asp.net-4.0, restsharp

I am trying to call a REST service from a C# ASP.NET 4.0 application using RestSharp.

It's a fairly straightforward POST call to a https:// address; my code is something like this (`CheckStatusRequest` is a plain simple DTO with about four or five `string` and `int` properties - nothing fancy):

```
public CheckStatusResponse CheckStatus(CheckStatusRequest request) {
    // set up RestClient
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    string uri = "https://.......";

    // create the request (see below)
    IRestRequest restRequest = CreateRequestWithHeaders(url, Method.POST);

    // add the body to the request
    restRequest.AddBody(request);

    // execute call
    var restResponse = _restClient.Execute<CheckStatusResponse>(restRequest);
}   

// set up request
private IRestRequest CreateRequestWithHeaders(string uri, Method method) {
    // define request
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(uri, method);

    // add two required HTTP headers
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // define JSON as my format
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    // attach the JSON.NET serializer for RestSharp
    request.JsonSerializer = new RestSharpJsonNetSerializer();

    return request;
}
```

The problem I'm having when I send these requests through Fiddler to see what's going on is that my request suddenly gets a *third* and unwanted HTTP header:

```
POST https://-some-url- HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: RestSharp/104.4.0.0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: **********.com
Content-Length: 226
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate   <<<=== This one here is UNWANTED!
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I suddenly have that `Accept-Encoding` HTTP header, which I never specified (and which I don't want to have in there). And now my response is no longer proper JSON (which I'm able to parse), but suddenly I get back gzipped binary data instead (which doesn't do real well when trying to JSON-deserialize)....

How can I get rid of that third unwanted HTTP header?

- I tried to set it to something else - whatever I enter just gets appended to those settings
- I tried to somehow "clear" that HTTP header - without any success
- I tried finding a property on the RestClient or the RestRequest classes to specify "do not use GZip"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the sources ([Http.Sync.cs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Http.Sync.cs#L270) and [Http.Async.cs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Http.Async.cs#L445)) of RestSharp you can see that these values are hardcoded:

```
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = 
    DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.None;
```

There is also an open [issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/561) that describes this problem. It was opened August 2014 but still not solved. I think you can leave a comment there and maybe they will pay attention.

Comment: Thanks - I'm torn between hoping that the RestSharp team will add this to the official release some day soon, and creating my own custom version of RestSharp....